# Delphi Format Strings - limits for width and precision values?

Tags: delphi, formatting, delphi-7, number-formatting

This statement (in Delphi 7)

```
writeln(logfile,format('%16.16d ',[FileInfo.size])+full_name);
```

results in this output

```
0000000021239384 C:\DATA\DELPHI\sxf_archive10-13.zip
```

This statement

```
writeln(logfile,format('%17.17d ',[FileInfo.size])+full_name);
```

results in this output

```
         21239384 C:\DATA\DELPHI\sxf_archive10-13.zip
```

The padding with leading zeros changes to leading spaces when the precision specifier is larger than 16.  The help says "If the format string contains a precision specifier, it indicates that the resulting string must contain at least the specified number of digits; if the value has less digits, the resulting string is left-padded with zeros."

Is there another way to format a 20 character integer with leading zeros?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Precision of an `Integer` value is limited to 16 digits max.  If the specified Precision is larger than 16, 0 is used instead.  This is not a bug, it is hard-coded logic, and is not documented.

There are two ways you can handle this:

1. use an `Int64` instead of an `Integer`.  Precision for an `Int64` is 32 digits max:

   ```
   WriteLn(logfile, Format('%20.20d %s', [Int64(FileInfo.Size), full_name]);
   ```

   Note: In Delphi 2006 and later, `TSearchRec.Size` is an `Int64`.  In earlier versions, it is an `Integer` instead, and thus limited to 2GB. If you need to handle file sizes > 2GB in earlier versions, you can get the full 64-bit size from the `TSearchRec.FindData` field:

   ```
   var
     FileSize: ULARGE_INTEGER;
   begin
     FileSize.LowPart := FileInfo.FindData.nFileSizeLow;
     FileSize.HighPart := FileInfo.FindData.nFileSizeHigh:
     WriteLn(logfile, Format('%20.20d %s', [FileSize.QuadPart, full_name]);
   end;
   ```
2. convert the `Integer` to a string without any leading zeros, and then use `StringOfChar()` to prepend any required zeros:

   ```
   s := IntToStr(FileInfo.Size);
   if Length(s) < 20 then
     s := StringOfChar('0', 20-Length(s)) + s;
   WriteLn(logfile, s + ' ' + full_name);
   ```

Comment: Thanks! That is the right way to do this - if I hadn't made the size 64 bit, it would have eventually failed on a >2GB file.  When I added the "windows" unit to the uses list for the ULARGE_INTEGER type, it caused an error elsewhere on "Findclose". I had to track down that the Windows unit defines a different findclose procedure, so I had to change my usage to Sysutils.findclose.